# String or enum as parameter to refer to model fields

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I have a situation in which I have a model having 5 fields with getter and setters, say **id, name, age, dob, city**

A service class contains a method which is bound to return only specific fields data in form of an array. Like I want only name and age of all people.

```
List<Object> getEmpDataAsList(List<Object> fields);
```

So my method look like this which expects one parameter `fields` which contains list of fields that are needed to be returned. So for this case, I should send just `name` and `age` to fields parameter and my `getEmpDataAsList` detects fields asked for and build a return array accordingly.

I was wondering what is the best way of doing it. Should I pass `fields` List  as String which I am also doing at present, like:

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add("name");
fields.add("age");

getEmpDataAsList(fields);
```

But I think, this is not safe. What if I plan to change name of a field one day or what if I remove a field from model, then I need to make changes at 3 places. Should I make an enum in model class and use enum fields to create this same `fields` array and use it? Or is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Is the service `getEmpDataAsList(List<Object>)` given or are you allowed to change it?

Comment: @Chris Ya I have complete right over the project and I can change it anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I plan to change name of a field one day or what if I remove a
>   field from model, then I need to make changes at 3 places.

There is no solution to that problem. If you remove a field, it's gone. You have to remove it from the model and client. But here is a quick solution to make changes obvious, so that changing the API results in compile errors.

**Use generics in an abstract parent class to check the argument list while compiling:**

```
public abstract class GenericDataInterface<KEY extends Enum> {
    public abstract Object getData(KEY key);

    public final List<Object> getEmpDataAsList(List<KEY> fields) {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>(fields.size());
        for (KEY field : fields) {
            result.add(getData(field));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Example model class:**

```
public class Pizza extends GenericDataInterface<Pizza.PizzaAttributes> {
    public enum PizzaAttributes { NAME, TOPPINGS, PRICE };

    private String name;
    private Set<String> toppings;
    // WARNING: Do not use Float for prices in real applications!
    private float price;

    @Override
    public Object getData(PizzaAttributes key) {
        switch (key) {
            case NAME:
                return name;
            case TOPPINGS:
                return toppings;
            case PRICE:
                return price;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Key " + key + " isn't defined for " + Pizza.class.getCanonicalName());
        }
    }
}
```

The result isn't very convenient yet, because twists in order would result in unseen problems. Therefore you could **use a Map as result**:

```
public abstract class GenericDataInterface<KEY extends Enum> {
    public abstract Object getData(KEY key);

    public final Map<KEY, Object> getEmpDataAsList(List<KEY> fields) {
        Map<KEY, Object> result = new HashMap<KEY, Object>(fields.size());
        for (KEY field : fields) {
            result.put(field, getData(field));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Instead of a Map you could also use a clone of the real model class and fill only the specified attributes.

**Further thoughts:**

- Do you really need such a generic interface?
- If it's about network communication, can't you use XML or JSON?

Comment: You shouldn't use a raw type `KEY extends Enum`. Either type it to something or leave it as unknown `Enum<?>`, but not the raw type.

Comment: @Bohemian: Why? You'll never manually inherit from Enum anyway.

Comment: because Enum is a generic class. The right way to bound to an enum is `<KEY extends Enum<KEY>>`

Comment: I like your model's `getData()` method, it really fits well into the scene. But I do not really understand what is the need to create `GenericDataInterface`. Isn't it more clean by dkatzel answer, as the ultimate aim is to provide an API which cause compile errors if any change is made in model and also to make a developer know which fields he can use in this method call? And I am not looking for network communication. Please help me understand the need to `GenericDataInterface`, how is it going to help more?

Comment: @Ahbi: I assumed that you have more than one model class, so you could reuse some code in `GenericDataInterface`. `getEmpDataAsList` is probably already part of an interface or abstract class, so that shouldn't be a problem. dkatzels answer is just a simpler version of mine. Mine will also cause compile errors. With dkatzerls solution you cannot have a common interface, because each model class has a different enum as argument.

Comment: Some methods of [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) are generic. These methods would only be available in their raw form if they bound is raw, which may make certain code impossible. Also, it's best practice to never use raw types.

Comment: Thanks, it provided me many generic hints to address this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use an enum for the different field types. (Although, I don't know if AGE and DOB are both needed since you can compute age from the current date and DOB...)

```
public enum Fields{
  NAME,
  DOB,
  CITY
   ...


 }
```

This way you can have a more intent revealing API.

```
List<Object> getEmpDataAsList(Fields...fields)
```

or

```
List<Object> getEmpDataAsList(Set<Fields> fields)
```

which would let you do things like

```
results = getEmpDataAsList(Fields.AGE, Fields.DOB);
```

or

```
results = getEmpDataAsList(EnumSet.of(Fields.AGE, Fields.DOB));
```

If you have total control over the API I would recommend to also change the return type from List to Map so you can know what value is for which field without knowing or caring the input field order.

```
Map<Fields,Object> getEmpData(Fields...fields)
```

**What if I plan to change name of a field one day or what if I remove a field from model, then I need to make changes at 3 places.**

With an enum, if you rename the enum, the IDE can auto-rename all references for you.  If you remove an enum, you will get a compiler error so you know what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like simplicity of this, I am going to use much of it in my present situation :)